# Symfony Callback Validation with Yaml

Tags: php, validation, symfony, yaml, symfony-2.7

My validation is not being called when defined using validation.yml.
Using php or annotation everything works just fine.

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

class LoginForm
{
    private $login;
    private $password;

    public function __construct($login, $password)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        $context->buildViolation('Error')
            ->atPath('login')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

This is my validation.yml

```
AppBundle\Form\LoginForm:
    constraints:
        - Callback: [validate]
```

And this is my controller

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $login = $request->request->get('loginform_login');
            $password = $request->request->get('loginform_password');
            $form = new LoginForm($login, $password);
            $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($form);
            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                return $this->render('login/error.html.twig');
            }
            return $this->render('login/ok.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->render('login/login.html.twig');
    }
}
```

The above code always returns 'ok', no matter which login or password i type.
Any clue?

Comment: How are you adding the constraint with the other two approaches? Are you adding them to the class specified in your form's `data_class` property?

Most examples I've seen in the cookbooks, and most instances I've personally encountered, tend to add constraints to a *particular* field, not a form. Hence why I ask.

Comment: If i got it right, callback is class scoped. I used the other aproaches as shown here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: That's true, but scoped to an entity class, in the cookbook example, not a form class. Is the example you provided your full login form? Do you have a data_class set for it (set via `configureOptions/setDefaultOptions`)?

Comment: Actually my form class is just a regular class that i want to perform some kind of data validation (I think people call it Adhoc validation). As you can see i doesn't inherit from Symfony form class, nether is an Entity class. Answering your question, 'yes', it's my full login form. I don't believe validation is binded to Entity classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `validation.yml` file in `Resources/config` directory of your bundle.

As of Symfony 2.7 it Symfony will also load files from the `Resources/config/validation` directory.

Quoting the [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html):

> As of Symfony 2.7, XML and Yaml constraint files located in the Resources/config/validation sub-directory of a bundle are loaded. Prior to 2.7, only Resources/config/validation.yml (or .xml) were loaded.

Some examples of valid paths:

- src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
- src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation/foo.yml

Comment: Sorry, i got confused about `app/Resources` and `src/AppBundle/Resources`, which does not exists by default.

Comment: @vbsessa Saw your comment in my reply, but suspect you intended it for here. The file where that loading is taking place is [here](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/fab6822/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L770). As to why it takes that approach when other components can look globally in app/Resources is a more high level question. This is conjecture, but I suspect it to be an artifact of Symfony being built to handle projects with > 1 bundles. Only looking in one global location would lead to a bit too much cross-bundle mingling.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our back and forth in the comments, and the provided example, everything looks good compared against current cookbook examples. We're firmly in the brainstorm/"see what sticks" arena. Below are a few remaining thoughts:

1. Could your `validation.yml` file not be getting parsed/loaded? You might try adding some other property-level constraints to the file, just to rule out the callback as an outlier.
2. You could try the [`lint:yaml`](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-productivity-improvements#moved-lint-commands-to-the-lint-namespace) CLI tool, though from prior encounters I'd expect any malformed YAML would throw a more explicit parsing error.
3. *Extremely* unlikely (esp. after the recent documentation blitz), but perhaps the cookbook examples are not up to date, and configuration behavior has somehow changed.
4. Fire up XDebug and start stepping through the validation process. Ensure you actually hit your validate callback. If not, try using an external or static callback approach, just to see if that alleviates the issue.

Barring any of the above, I'll await a more informed answer than my own, with much interest!

Comment: I've tried `login: NotBlank` and it's not working. I think my validation.yml is not being loaded. I did a search about this issue and i saw people saying that this line `validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }` in config.yml should do that, but it's not. :/

Comment: A brand new project should already include a validation.yml? Because i'm having to manually create one and it's not being loaded at all.

Comment: Why all Resources, ie, non-PHP files can live in app/Resources except validation.yml? It's kind of weird, mainly when developing an app without any bundle.